# Can't install GhostScript in ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick, ghostscript

Download latest version of ImageMagick. Unpacked it. Installing Ghostscript like this:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ghostscript
```

After that try to configure ImageMagick:

```
$ ./configure --with-gslib
$ make
$ make install
```

After that i try to conver PDF to jpg

```
$ sudo /usr/local/bin/convert in.pdf out.jpg
```

And i see this mistake

```
convert: no decode delegate for this image format `/tmp/magick-BzHdr4Kp-00000001' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/544.
convert: Postscript delegate failed `in.PDF': Нет такого файла или каталога @ error/pdf.c/ReadPDFImage/678.
convert: no images defined `out.jpg' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3044.
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you `./configure` --with-gslib` complete without any errors or obvious warnings (like `Couldn't find gslib -- building without...`)? The error message is in part in Russian -- is that your `locale`?

Comment: Yes, i'm from Russia. There are no errors after ./configure --with-gslib

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following `convert` commands to see more precisely what's possibly going wrong:

```
 convert a.pdf -debug coder a.jpg
 convert a.pdf -debug all   a.jpg
```

There will possibly be a lot of output going to stderr. Amongst the lines you may see where IM is looking for Ghostscript. Also, try

```
 convert -list delegate 
 convert -list delegate | grep --color -E '(eps|pdf)'
```

to find with which exact commandlines ImageMagick tries to run Ghostscript (it may call `gsx` instead of `gs`, or it may look for it in `/usr/local/bin/`...). If you find any deviations from your real Ghostscript installation, you can possibly fix it by editing `delegates.xml`.

```
 convert -list configure
```

will show you how ImageMagick is configured (and if, for example, `gs` was during compile-time in the list in `DELEGATES` variables). Here you also find where to look for `delegates.xml`:

```
 convert -list configure | grep CONFIGURE_PATH
```

should list the directory where this (as well as some more) *.xml settings files are located which control how `convert` et al. behave...